# How do I call a UDF in a select statement?

Tags: sql-server, udf

How do I develop a tabular UDF that does not accept any values and calculates the commission for each employee_id.
I have a table called called campaign offer

```
Create Table Campaign_Offer
(
Offer_id            integer identity(1,1) primary key,
Offer_date          Date        ,
Customer_id         int ,
Offer_value         money       ,
Product_name        varchar(20) ,
Acceptance_status   varchar(3)  ,
Employee_ID         char(10)    ,

Constraint CustomerID foreign key (Customer_id) references marketing_list(Id),
Constraint EmployeeID foreign key (Employee_ID) references Employee(Employee_id),
Constraint AcceptanceStatus Check (Acceptance_status in ('yes', 'no'))
)
```

This is the function I am trying to call

```
Create Function OfferCommission (@OfferValue money,@OfferDate date)
Returns money
As
Begin
RETURN @OfferValue * CHOOSE(DATEPART(QUARTER,@OfferDate), 0.1, 0.15, 0.2,    
0.25) 
END
```

I was trying it here

```
Create Function TabularCommission
(
@Offer_id           integer,
@Offer_value            money,
@Acceptance_status  varchar(3)  

)Returns table
As
Return
(
Select Employee_ID,dbo.OfferCommission(Offer_value, Offer_date) as  
Commission from Campaign_Offer
where Acceptance_status = 'yes'
group by Employee_ID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to pass parameters to your outer function

```
Create Function TabularCommission()
Returns table
As
Return
(
Select Employee_ID
      ,dbo.OfferCommission(Offer_value, Offer_date) as Commission 
from Campaign_Offer
where Acceptance_status = 'yes'
)
```

Comment: thanks but I'm getting Column 'Campaign_Offer.Offer_value because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You dont need `group by` here

Comment: If for some reason you do really want to have a GROUP BY then you need this.  group by Employee_ID, dbo.OfferCommission(Offer_value, Offer_date)           or you may just want a DISTINCT after the select.